# Two Apps getting same notification message when i integrated my modules with that Apps

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, message, localbroadcastmanager

I am using android studio and i struck in implementing broadcast in my app so that it should trigger only one App and i'm using Localbroadcastmanager  for registering and unregistering

```
    Android Phone

    APP1     APP2 

     My Modules
```

I have integrated **MyModules** with two apps installed in one Android phone.

When i send a message to **APP1** from some other Android phone  it receives message to APP1 But both **APP1** and **APP2** triggers the notification at a same time.

My **BroadcastService.java**

```
   public static void sendNotificationBroadcast(Context context, Message message) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Sending notification broadcast...");
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MyConstants.MESSAGE_JSON_INTENT, GsonUtils.getJsonFromObject(message, Message.class));
    notificationIntent.setAction("com.notification.send");
    context.sendBroadcast(notificationIntent);
}
```

i'm setting my intent action **"com.notification.send"**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver android:name="com.notification.NotificationBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.notification.send"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This is my **NotificationBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class NotificationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "NotificationBroadcastReceiver";
private static String NOTIFICATION_ICON_METADATA = "com.notification.icon";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();

        Integer notificationIconId = Utils.getMetaDataValueForResources(context, NOTIFICATION_ICON_METADATA);

        String messageJson = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.MESSAGE_JSON_INTENT);
        Log.i(TAG, "Received broadcast, action: " + action + ", message: " + messageJson);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageJson)) {
            final Message message = (Message) GsonUtils.getObjectFromJson(messageJson, Message.class);
            final NotificationService notificationService =
                    new NotificationService(notificationIconId == null ? R.drawable.ic_launcher : notificationIconId, context, R.string.wearable_action_label, R.string.wearable_action_title, R.drawable.ic_action_send);

            final Contact contact = new contactService(context).getContactById(message.getIds());
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    notificationService.notifyUser(contact, message);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
  }
```

both Apps are listening to same broadcast, How to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

i fixed this problem by using context.getPackageName() i have appended with my action

**BroadcastService.java**

```
    intent.setAction(context.getPackageName()+".send");
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="YOUR ANDROID APP PACKAGENAME.send"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Google Cloud Messaging to push to the device. Make sure each app uses a different GCM sender id or channel.

Comment: i'm  using different GCM sender id for different apps

Comment: @sunil Ah - ok. I had a similar issue the other day and this was the problem.

Comment: @ Richard Le Mesurier thanks for your reply :) i have one question can i ask?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the broadcast to originating app only set *package* on the intent:

```
intent.setPackage(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage(java.lang.String)